# How to fix shapes (3,) and (720,1440) not aligned error

Tags: python, astronomy

I am attempting to use the normal equation to produce a Fermi Map. However, I keep running into an error. Here is where I am with my code so far:

''''
#_=0+1×_+2×ℎ_
#=_−(0+1×_+2×ℎ_)
#These are the normal equations, so let's solve them

```
P = np.array([np.ones(dust_map.size),dust_map, synch_map]).T
PTy = np.dot(P.T, fermi_gamma_rays)
PTP = np.dot (P.T,P)
PTPi = np.linalg.inv(PTP)
avec = np.dot(PTPi, PTy)
print("avec = {0}".format(avec))
```

''''

The error I keep receiving says shapes (3,) and (720,1440) not aligned: 3 (dim 0) != 720 (dim 0).

The dust_map, fermi_gamma_rays, and synchtron_map are all 720x1140 ndarrays that were imported from a data file using nd.load

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
P = np.array([np.ones_like(dust_map).flatten(),dust_map.flatten(), synch_map.flatten()])
avec = np.linalg.lstsq(P.T, fermi_gamma_rays.flatten(),  rcond=None)[0]
```